# How can I send this multiple json onChange to GET or POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I do some reordering and move some items between lists
I want to put ALL changed serialized outputs in a variable (in order) and sent it in a post (or get) every time one of them change. I try, but I figured out that I can't apply onChange on text area that contain serialized output because sometimes there are cases (move item between lists) when two change simultaneous. How can i do this? A new json with all individual jsons will be also ok I think. I used this code:
https://dbushell.com/Nestable/
https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

```
        var updateOutput = function(e)
        {
            var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
                output = list.data('output');
            if (window.JSON) {output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));/*, null, 2));*/}
            else {output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');}
        };
        // activate Nestable for list 1
        $('#nestable1').nestable({group: 1})
        .on('change', updateOutput);
        // activate Nestable for list 2
        $('#nestable2').nestable({group: 1})
        .on('change', updateOutput);
        // output initial serialised data
        updateOutput($('#nestable1').data('output', $('#nestable1-output')));
        updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));
        $('#nestable-menu').on('click', function(e)
            {
                var target = $(e.target),
                action = target.data('action');
                if (action === 'expand-all')   {$('.dd').nestable('expandAll');}
                if (action === 'collapse-all') {$('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');}
            });
    });
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us the HTML as well. Maybe in a snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/ ? See jsfiddle.com

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/razvanx/8odk2vwy/22/

Comment: `What do you mean `because sometimes there are cases (move item between lists) when two change simultaneous` ???` Simultaneous because different users are using the site??? Or simultaneous because I drag and drop a group???

Also, why not send the whole serialized output???

Comment: This library has a serialized json in a text area for each group. If I change order of list item(s) in a group, json in corespondent text area is changing. But if I move the item(s) to another group, there will be changings in two text areas. The problem is that I dont know how to trigger a function when something is changing, a function that will have a input var with whole serialized output

Comment: ```function onListUpdate(wholeJson){
 if(window.loadingPendding==false){
   window.loadingPendding==true;
   http.open('get','updateDB.php?newLists='+wholeJson+'&nocache='+Math.random());
   http.onreadystatechange=loadListReply;
   http.send(null);
 }
 else {alert ("Wait for completion of the previous operation!")}  
}```

Comment: I found a way to do it, but only if know exactly if an item was moved to another group or within the same group. How can I

Comment: Why not send both text area JSONs to the server?

Answer (score 0):

### Initial Answer

`onListUpdate` is the proper method that you should write your post code in.

You can use the [JQuery Post Method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Quick Rough Example:

```
     var updateOutput = function(e)
        {
            var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
                output = list.data('output');
            if (window.JSON) {output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));/*, null, 2));*/}
            else {output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');

$.post( "test.php", output.val );

}
        };
```

Or Maybe:     `list.nestable('serialize')`

### Tracking Changes

I would add additional attributes/data to your fields. So, you have a `children` field. I would also add a `parent` data attribute. Additionally, I would add a `previousParent`. This way you will be able to detect when the current parent does not match the previous parent.

Comment: How do I know if an item was moved to another group or within the same group?

Comment: Why not send both text area JSONs to the server? It's the simples solution. Otherwise, you will have to keep track of who the parent was for each node.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution, but the problem is that I don't know how to do it corectly. I don't know how to wait untill all text areas are done, without using setTimeout.

Comment: Oh that’s not too tough. Make two global variables that are booleans. Put an on ‘change’ event handler on both of them. When handler1 is called set flag1 to true. When handler2 is called set flag2 to true. Also have a common method checkFlags. This will check flag1 and flag2. When both are true, send the message. Then set flag1 and flag2 to false. Call checkFlags from handler1 and handler2.

Comment: Same problem...If element is moved inside it's own grup there will be no more changes in textarea 2... :(